# how to set button invisible depending on another activity

Tags: java, android

In my activity I add to it some stuff by checking checkbox and if 
    `list.size()>0` (this condition is in my adapter) shows up button which is redirecting me to second activity. In second activity I display listview filled with items from static list , when I click on it i delete object from list, also Ive made button in second activity which make this `list.clear(); finish();`  When I return to first activity i've still visible button even if static list was cleared. How to solve it ? I need the simplest ideas becouse i'm a beginner in android. All answers, suggestions, clues are wellcome. If you don't know how to do it, pop up thread. Thank you for your time.

```
public class TowarAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Towar> {

private List<Towar> items;
private Activity context;
private int i = 0;
ImageButton b_zatwierdz;
int counter = 0;
boolean user_checked = false;


public int getI() {
    return i;
}

public void setI(int i) {
    this.i = i;
}

public TowarAdapter(Activity context, int resource, List<Towar> items,
        ImageButton b_zatwierdz) {

    super(context, resource);

    this.b_zatwierdz = b_zatwierdz;
    this.items = items;
    this.context = context;
}

public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return items.size();
}

@Override
public Towar getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return items.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView tvNazwaT;
    TextView tvCenaT;
    ImageView ivTowar;
    CheckBox chb_czy_zamowic;
}

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder view;
    // LayoutInflater inflator = activity.getLayoutInflater();
    LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if (convertView == null) {
        view = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.element, null);

        view.tvNazwaT = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvNazwaT);
        view.tvCenaT = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvCenaT);
        view.chb_czy_zamowic = (CheckBox) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.chb_czy_zamowic);
        view.ivTowar = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivTowar);

        convertView.setTag(view);
    } else {
        view = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    view.tvNazwaT.setText(items.get(position).getTow_nazwa());
    view.tvNazwaT.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    view.tvCenaT.setText(items.get(position).getTow_cena() + "zł");

    for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
        String s = Integer.valueOf(items.get(position).Kat_id).toString();
        int resourceId = context.getResources().getIdentifier("a" + s + i,
                "drawable", context.getPackageName());
        view.ivTowar.setImageResource(resourceId);
    }

    view.chb_czy_zamowic
            .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(
                        final CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if (buttonView.isChecked()) {

                        user_checked = true;

                        if (user_checked == true) {
                            final Dialog d1 = new Dialog(context);
                            d1.setContentView(R.layout.ilosc);
                            d1.getWindow()
                                    .setSoftInputMode(
                                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
                            d1.setTitle("Wybierz ilość");

                            final EditText et_Ilosc;
                            Button b_Ok;
                            Button b_Odejmij;
                            Button b_Dodaj;

                            et_Ilosc = (EditText) d1
                                    .findViewById(R.id.et_Ilosc);

                            et_Ilosc.setText(String.valueOf(i));

                            view.chb_czy_zamowic.setClickable(false);

                            b_Dodaj = (Button) d1
                                    .findViewById(R.id.b_Dodaj);
                            b_Dodaj.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    String zmienna_pom = et_Ilosc.getText()
                                            .toString();
                                    i = Integer.valueOf(zmienna_pom);
                                    if (i < 0) {
                                        Toast t = Toast.makeText(
                                                getContext(),
                                                "Niepoprawna wartość",
                                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                                        t.show();
                                    } else if (i == items.get(position)
                                            .getTow_ilosc_value()) {
                                        Toast t = Toast
                                                .makeText(
                                                        getContext(),
                                                        "Osiągnięto wartość maksymalną "
                                                                + items.get(
                                                                        position)
                                                                        .getTow_ilosc_value(),
                                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                                        t.show();
                                    } else if (i > items.get(position)
                                            .getTow_ilosc_value()) {

                                        Toast t = Toast
                                                .makeText(
                                                        getContext(),
                                                        "Przekroczono wartość maksymalną "
                                                                + items.get(
                                                                        position)
                                                                        .getTow_ilosc_value(),
                                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                                        t.show();
                                    }

                                    else if (et_Ilosc.getText().toString()
                                            .equals("")) {
                                        Toast t = Toast.makeText(
                                                getContext(),
                                                "Uzupełnij pole ilość",
                                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                                        t.show();
                                    } else {
                                        setI(i);
                                        int k = getI();
                                        k++;

                                        setI(k);
                                        et_Ilosc.setText(String.valueOf(i));

                                    }
                                }
                            });
                            b_Odejmij = (Button) d1
                                    .findViewById(R.id.b_Odejmij);
                            b_Odejmij
                                    .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(View v) {
                                            String zmienna_pom = et_Ilosc
                                                    .getText().toString();
                                            i = Integer
                                                    .valueOf(zmienna_pom);
                                            if (i < 0) {
                                                Toast t = Toast
                                                        .makeText(
                                                                getContext(),
                                                                "Niepoprawna wartość",
                                                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                                                t.show();
                                            } else if (et_Ilosc.getText()
                                                    .toString().equals("")) {
                                                Toast t = Toast
                                                        .makeText(
                                                                getContext(),
                                                                "Uzupełnij pole ilość",
                                                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                                                t.show();
                                            } else {
                                                setI(i);
                                                i--;
                                                setI(i);
                                                et_Ilosc.setText(String
                                                        .valueOf(i));
                                            }

                                        }
                                    });
                            b_Ok = (Button) d1.findViewById(R.id.b_Ok);
                            b_Ok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    String zmiennna_pom = et_Ilosc
                                            .getText().toString();
                                    int k = Integer.valueOf(zmiennna_pom);

                                    if (k <= 0
                                            || k > items.get(position)
                                                    .getTow_ilosc_value()) {
                                        Toast t = Toast
                                                .makeText(
                                                        getContext(),
                                                        "Wybierz z przedziału 1-"
                                                                + items.get(
                                                                        position)
                                                                        .getTow_ilosc_value(),
                                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                                        t.show();
                                    } else if (et_Ilosc.getText()
                                            .toString().equals("")) {
                                        Toast t = Toast.makeText(
                                                getContext(),
                                                "Uzupełnij pole ilość",
                                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                                        t.show();
                                    } else {
                                        view.chb_czy_zamowic
                                                .setEnabled(false);

                                        // String zmiennna_pom = et_Ilosc
                                        // / .getText().toString();
                                        // int k = Integer
                                        // .valueOf(zmiennna_pom);

                                        items.get(position).Tow_ilosc -= k;
                                        Towar checkedObject = new Towar();
                                        checkedObject.Tow_ilosc = k;
                                        checkedObject.Kat_id = items
                                                .get(position).Kat_id;
                                        checkedObject.kategoria = items
                                                .get(position).kategoria;
                                        checkedObject.Tow_cena = items
                                                .get(position).Tow_cena;
                                        checkedObject.Tow_id = items
                                                .get(position).Tow_id;
                                        checkedObject.Tow_nazwa = items
                                                .get(position).Tow_nazwa;
                                        MainActivity.lista_wybranych_towarow
                                                .add(checkedObject);
                                        k = 0;
                                        setI(0);
                                        // et_Ilosc.setText("");
                                        d1.dismiss();

                                    }

                                    // view.chb_czy_zamowic.setChecked(false);

                                    if (MainActivity.lista_wybranych_towarow
                                            .size() > 0) {
                                        b_zatwierdz
                                                .setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                    }
                                    else
                                        b_zatwierdz
                                        .setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                                }
                            });
                            d1.show();
                        }
                        ;

                    }
                }

            });

    return convertView;

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To make the button invisible, you need to do the following (I'm just mentioning the logic for hiding the button - you will have to implement this in a listener):

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.layout.button_id); // Point it to the button
if(list_is_empty) {
    button.setVisibility(Button.GONE); // This line hides the button
}
```

Know that in Android, 'GONE' is used to hide the element from the view and this space is now available in the layout. 'INVISIBLE' means that while the widget is hidden, the space for this widget is still unavailable.

Comment: I did - you have made the button visible but there is no logic implemented to hide the button once the list is cleared. You have the logic for it to show up and so it shows up but not for it to hide. You need to explicitly state that. Can you show a bit of code? Because there are several ways to do this and this is the easiest.

Comment: my logic have both statement solved

    if (MainActivity.staticList.size() > 0) {
           button_ok
             .setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

          }
          else
           button_ok
           .setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

Comment: look above, that is my logic for now

Comment: This has to be inside a listener which is attached to a widget(ArrayAdapter) so that it will be triggered when the list is empty. The listener is the triggering mechanism.

Comment: not able to open pastebin. it is blocked in pakistan

Comment: your code is difficult to read.where you have place the code for shared preferences.

Answer (score 0):

You could put an extra in the intent when calling the activity, or save the flag in a shared preference. Then depending on the flag you can set the visibility to true or false?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `startActivityForResult` here. when you `delete object from list`. pass back the `boolean where like 'isDelete'` and check this variable in `onActivityResult` (it is first activity) if it is `true i.e object is delete` so set button `visibility` to false else do nothing.

you can also used sharedpreferences here. track the boolean variable and depending on its value set the button visibility.

for shared preference do this :

when you delete object do this, to write boolean value to shared preferences

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);  //creating object of shared preference
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();  //getting editor to write value
  editor.putBoolean("isShow",false);  //first value is key and second is the value which you are going to assign it
  editor.commit();


and in your main adapter class do :

SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
boolean show = preferences.getBoolean("isShow",false);  //first value is key and second value is used if isShow is not defined.

if(show)
//show the button

else
//hide the button
```

Comment: but the logic of the button visibility is in MainAdapter.class not in MainActivity.class. if startActivityForResult will work in that case ?

Comment: then i guess sharedpreference will work better in this case.when ever object get delete set boolean variable to true and then check that variable in main adapter class and set button visibility according to that.

Comment: could you give me an example ? I never used SharedPreferences. I'm a beginner.

Comment: also could you tell me if SharedPrefs will change anything when (as someone wiser than me told) onResume() method is executing after finish my previous activity ?

Comment: also here is my adapter class  pastebin.com/H6HAswnJ

Comment: link is not opening. i guess it may be blocked in pakistan.

Comment: no. sharedpreference will remain there untill your app is not uninstallled.

Comment: i edited post, take a look on it. this is my adapter